# Running app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3, androidstudio-settings

I have an Asus Zenfone 2 Laser and I'm using android studio to create apps. When I load an application stored in the hard disk of my computer for debugging, no problems, but when the application is stored in a USB device, at first android studio warns that there is already a version of the same app in my phone and asks if it has to uninstall it in order to install the new version; when I click the button to uninstall it, it doesn't install the new one...

[image]
How can I fix the problem? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'when the application is stored in a USB device'? Is the `.apk` file stored on a USB device or your source code?

Comment: @AbhijitParida source code

Comment: They are different versions probably, one signed with debug key and one with release? You can have Gradle append a string depending on the version to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can - Try these steps one by one

1. Completely uninstall the app from your phone
2. On Android Studio click on BUILD->CLEAN PROJET
3. On Android Studio click on BUILD->BUILD APK
4. An APK will be created on your HardDisk at the save location
5. Copy and Paste the newly created APK from COMPUTER to PHONE using USB cable
6. Install the new App manually
7. Now try to build and launch the app to phone via Android Studio
8. From now, it will be automatically installed and loaded

Hope it solves...