# How do I put an app I did in Android Studio in my phone?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have made an app in Android Studio. I want to have it in my phone and use it whenever I want, but I don't know how. I don't want to publish it into the Play Store, I just want to use it for myself. How do I do it? :)

Comment: I believe this is already answered here:
----------
[Running app in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247280/8980525)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running app in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247144/running-app-in-android-studio)

Comment: It kinda answers it, but it's outdated. The new Android Studio version requires a process more similar to jeprubio's answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Perform the following steps to enable **USB debugging** in the **Developer options** window:

  - Open the **Settings** app.
  - If your device uses Android v8.0 or higher, select **System**. Otherwise, proceed to the next step.
  - Scroll to the bottom and select **About phone**.
  - Scroll to the bottom and tap **Build number** seven times.
  - Return to the previous screen, scroll to the bottom, and tap **Developer options**.
  - In the **Developer options** window, scroll down to find and enable **USB debugging**.
- Connect your device to your development machine with a USB cable. If you developed on Windows, you might need to [install the appropriate USB driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) for your device. And make sure to select you trust the computer when prompted.
- In Android Studio, select your app from the run/debug configurations drop-down menu in the toolbar.
- In the toolbar, select the device that you want to run your app on from the target device drop-down menu.

[image: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/run/deploy-run-app.png]

- Click **Run** [image: run] and wait until the process finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the incredible support, and satisfaction you bring to me :) Considering the actual version of Android Studio 3.6.3, your answer was the best, jeprubio :) Thanks. And, what a timely intervention!